# Close session file Immediately in Zend

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I need to close session file immediately after write in Zend.

Two routes exist in my controller,`module1/controller1/action1` and `module2/controller2/action2` . **action1** one take long time to execute,so session file doesn't close until end of it.when session file is opened by **action1** ,the other actions should wait for session file to writable.

What is the best way to handle this problem?I don't need to handle session by Database.

-- edit

I need to do following in simple way:

```
while(something){
 // open session

 // write

 // close
}
```

Comment: `session_destroy()`? :)

Comment: @Sam I edited my question,I can't use it

Comment: Can you maybe tell more about what you're actually trying to do? Just going by your example i'd just put the session_destroy after the closing while ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework has Zend_Session lock(), unlock() and isLocked().